# If everything in Dart is an Object then why passing String and Integers variable and modifying it inside function will not change the value of object

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart is purely pass-by-value. The value passed when we're dealing with an object is an object reference, but that has nothing to do with "pass by reference."

Pass-by-reference means that a function can be passed a variable and change the contents of that variable in the calling function. That does not exist in Dart.

If everything in Dart is an Object then why passes String and Integers variable and modifying it inside function will not change the value of object just like it does when passing List.

```
listFunction(List<int> list, int x) {
  list.add(x);
}

stringFunction(String str, String suffix) {
  str += suffix;
}

intFunction(int x, int y) {
  x += y;
}

void main() {
  
  List<int> list = [1,2,3];
  
  print(list);
  listFunction(list, 4);
  listFunction(list, 5);
  print(list);

  String str = 'abcd';

  print(str);
  stringFunction(str, 'e');
  stringFunction(str, 'f');
  print(str);

  int x = 2;

  print(x);
  intFunction(x, 1);
  intFunction(x, 2);
  print(x);
}
```

[image: DartPad Link]

Comment: `List` is mutable. `String` and `int` are immutable.

Comment: `str += suffix` is shorthand for `str = str + suffix`.  It *reassigns* the *local* `str` variable; it does not mutate it.  Same thing for `x += y` with `int`s.